# Capturing sudden changes of data plotted in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I capture big changes in graph like this:

[image]

It is clear that there are 3 sudden curves which can be seen by eyes.

Can anyone help me to determine the start of each of them?

Comment: This is a problem of finding particular local maxima, but no one here is going to solve the problem for you. You should show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

`Matlab` has `findpeaks` function in signal toolbox (I think) doing exactly this.

Without that, a primitive solution can be done by finding the derivative of the signal and checking the zero crossings for local maximums and minimums.  Obviously if your signal is noisy you need to smooth it or handle false positives afterwards.